# How to deploy j2ee application on apache2 server

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, apache2, webserver

I want to deploy my j2ee application on apache2 web server. can anyone provide me a reference how to set up Apache and Tomcat to work together with Apache serving static content and forwarding the requests for dynamic content to Tomcat?
Or is it possible to deploy war file to apache2 web server without involving tomcat?

Thanks,
Farhan

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `mod_jk` plugin installed in your `apache2` server. `mod_jk` is the Tomcat-Apache plug-in that handles the communication between Tomcat and Apache.

Get more information from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html) and docs from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/)

Comment: it is not only for Tomcat but most of the java web servers

Comment: can anyone provide a tutorial from installation to deployment on apache2 web server?

Comment: I am new in deployment that's why need step wise process fr start to end

Comment: off course i did but not enough solution to start my deployment process apache http server...

Comment: I have installed apache2 on my machine but didn't know where to place EAR/WAR/project files, can u please instruct me after the installation process....